# Como deixar a tela sempre ligada com o app aberto?

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber como faço para que a tela fique ligada sem bloquear enquanto estiver com o meu app aberto.

Answer (score 3):

A melhor maneira de fazer isso é usar o [FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) em sua `Activity` (e somente em uma `Activity`, nunca em um serviço ou outro componente de aplicativo). Por exemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }
```

A vantagem desta abordagem é que não requer permissão especial, e a plataforma gerencia corretamente o usuário movendo-se entre aplicativos, sem que seu aplicativo precise se preocupar com a liberação de recursos não utilizados.

Outra maneira de implementar isso é no arquivo XML de layout do seu aplicativo, usando o atributo [android:keepScreenOn](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#keepScreenOn) :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Usando o `android:keepScreenOn="true"` é equivalente a usar `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`.

Você pode usar qualquer abordagem que seja melhor para seu aplicativo.

A vantagem de configurar de forma programática na sua `Activity` é que você 
oferece a opção de desligar a tela via código.

[FONTE](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)

Answer (score 2):

Antes do setContentView () use :

```
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Tem uma maneira melhor que seria um attribute no layout.xml mas nao lembro no momento

Comment: Obrigado Adliano Alves, vou testar esse código no projeto.